# AlarmManager Pending intent not working with broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, datetimepicker, android-pendingintent

I am working on an App in which i want to set custom alarm.but after setting a time on alarm nothing happens. i am sharing my code. Please help and guide me if something is missing in my code.

In my MainActivity.java

```
        @Override
          protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

                if (id == DIALOG_ID) {
        return new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, kTimePickerListener, hour, min, false);
    }
    return null;
}

protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener kTimePickerListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourofday, int minutes) {
                hour = hourofday;
                min = minutes;

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                // set selected time from timepicker to calendar

                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceManager.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("reqcode", 11);

                // A PendingIntent specifies an action to take in the
                // future
                PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 11, myIntent, 0);

                // set alarm time
                 alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), mPendingIntent);

            }
        };
```

In My ServiceManager.class

```
           public class ServiceManager extends BroadcastReceiver {



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int Noti_code = intent.getIntExtra("reqcode",-1);


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("reqcode", Noti_code);
        context.startService(myIntent);


}
}
```

In My NotificationService.class

```
    public class NotificationService extends Service {

private NotificationManager mManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@SuppressWarnings({"static-access", "deprecation"})
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    int Noti_Code = intent.getIntExtra("reqcode",-2);

    if (Noti_Code == 11) {
        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        ShowNotification(getApplicationContext(), mManager);
    } 


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

In my Manifest.xml

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity_detail" />
    <activity android:name=".History" />

    <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false"/>
    <receiver android:name=".ServiceManager"
        android:process=":remote"/>
</application>
```

I am checking through debugging broadcast receiver doesn't called. Please help me if i am missing any thing.
Also i want to know how many pending intent can be fire at a time and will all works one by one?

Thanks.

Refrence links:

[AlarmManager wont fire pending intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477762/alarmmanager-wont-fire-pending-intent)

http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/

[BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager not working with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722793/broadcastreceiver-and-alarmmanager-not-working-with)

[AlarmManager is not working after app is closed? - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771957/alarmmanager-is-not-working-after-app-is-closed-android)

Comment: You have your `BroadcastReceiver` running in another process. If you are setting breakpoints with a debugger you will miss this. If you don't need your `BroadcastReceiver` running in a separate process, remove the `android:process=":remote"` declaration from the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. let me do this and inform you if it works or not. and can you please tell me what is the purpose of Remote.i would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, now it working. and one more thing i want to ask is i am setting alarm for 12:00 AM by coding but its not triggering.
This is how i am getting time from calender :
    Calendar alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
      
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Comment: To set the alarm for midnight (12:00 AM), you need to use `set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)`. Alternatively you can use `set(Calendar.HOUR, 0)` **and** `set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM)`

Comment: for `android:process` refer to  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#proc this describes how specifying a name preceeded by a colon (":") causes the component to be launched in a separate OS process.

Comment: I'm happy this solved your problem. I added my suggestion as an answer below. You can accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions, and may help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks sir , this is really informative for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `BroadcastReceiver` running in another process. If you are setting breakpoints with a debugger you will miss this. If you don't need your `BroadcastReceiver` running in a separate process, remove the

```
android:process=":remote"
```

declaration from the manifest.

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#proc) about how the `android:process` specifier works.

Comment: I have been debugging an issue with my alarm for around one hour and finally found this answer. Thank you.